# How to get DOM element of current Vue component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, components, vue.js

When I'm inside some method in vue commponent and want to use some dom manipulation (by jquery) I need to get DOM element coresponnding to my component (especially in case when I have many instances of my component on page - I need to 'work' separately on each of them - so I cannot detect DOM element using only jquery selector without tricks...)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just by this (in any method in "methods"):

```
let domElement = this.$el;
```

:)

But remember this is valid as long as your component is not a [Fragment Instance](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance) i.e. it has a single root HTML tag

Comment: If you want to get the jQuery instance of the element: $(this.$el).

Comment: if using composition how do you get $el ? since you dont have access to `this`